# Resize image in Iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I am trying to resize image but its not working properly. i have an image width 320 and height 480 i want to resize it to width 1024 and height 1024. i am using this code to resize image

```
- (UIImage *)resizeImageToSize:(CGSize)targetSize
{
    UIImage *sourceImage = [self saveImage:0];

    UIImage *newImage = nil;

    CGSize imageSize = sourceImage.size;
    CGFloat width = imageSize.width;
    CGFloat height = imageSize.height;

    CGFloat targetWidth = targetSize.width;
    CGFloat targetHeight = targetSize.height;

    CGFloat scaleFactor = 0.0;
    CGFloat scaledWidth = targetWidth;
    CGFloat scaledHeight = targetHeight;

    CGPoint thumbnailPoint = CGPointMake(0.0,0.0);

    if (CGSizeEqualToSize(imageSize, targetSize) == NO) {

        CGFloat widthFactor = targetWidth / width;
        CGFloat heightFactor = targetHeight / height;

        if (widthFactor < heightFactor)
            scaleFactor = widthFactor;
        else
            scaleFactor = heightFactor;

        scaledWidth  = width * scaleFactor;
        scaledHeight = height * scaleFactor;

        // make image center aligned
        if (widthFactor < heightFactor)
        {
            thumbnailPoint.y = (targetHeight - scaledHeight) * 0.5;
        }
        else if (widthFactor > heightFactor)
        {
            thumbnailPoint.x = (targetWidth - scaledWidth) * 0.5;
        }
    }

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(targetSize);
    CGRect thumbnailRect = CGRectZero;
    thumbnailRect.origin = thumbnailPoint;
    thumbnailRect.size.width  = scaledWidth;
    thumbnailRect.size.height = scaledHeight;

    [sourceImage drawInRect:thumbnailRect];
    newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    if(newImage == nil)
        NSLog(@"could not scale image");

    return newImage ;
}
```

i am not getting image size what i want.

this is what i get when resizing image from 320x480 to 1280x1024
Image size is increasing but the image is not. i want that car to be stretched over white background[image].

Answer (score 2):

You want to resize and maintain aspect ratio try this .... it is very similar to the method above :

```
- (UIImage*)imageWithImage:(UIImage*)sourceImage scaledToSizeWithSameAspectRatio:(CGSize)targetSize;
{  
    CGSize imageSize = sourceImage.size;
    CGFloat width = imageSize.width;
    CGFloat height = imageSize.height;
    CGFloat targetWidth = targetSize.width;
    CGFloat targetHeight = targetSize.height;
    CGFloat scaleFactor = 0.0;
    CGFloat scaledWidth = targetWidth;
    CGFloat scaledHeight = targetHeight;
    CGPoint thumbnailPoint = CGPointMake(0.0,0.0);

    if (CGSizeEqualToSize(imageSize, targetSize) == NO) {
        CGFloat widthFactor = targetWidth / width;
        CGFloat heightFactor = targetHeight / height;

        if (widthFactor > heightFactor) {
            scaleFactor = widthFactor; // scale to fit height
        }
        else {
            scaleFactor = heightFactor; // scale to fit width
        }

        scaledWidth  = width * scaleFactor;
        scaledHeight = height * scaleFactor;

        // center the image
        if (widthFactor > heightFactor) {
            thumbnailPoint.y = (targetHeight - scaledHeight) * 0.5; 
        }
        else if (widthFactor < heightFactor) {
            thumbnailPoint.x = (targetWidth - scaledWidth) * 0.5;
        }
    }     

    CGImageRef imageRef = [sourceImage CGImage];
    CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo = CGImageGetBitmapInfo(imageRef);
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpaceInfo = CGImageGetColorSpace(imageRef);

    if (bitmapInfo == kCGImageAlphaNone) {
        bitmapInfo = kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast;
    }

    CGContextRef bitmap;

    if (sourceImage.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationUp || sourceImage.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationDown) {
        bitmap = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, targetWidth, targetHeight, CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(imageRef), CGImageGetBytesPerRow(imageRef), colorSpaceInfo, bitmapInfo);

    } else {
        bitmap = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, targetHeight, targetWidth, CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(imageRef), CGImageGetBytesPerRow(imageRef), colorSpaceInfo, bitmapInfo);

    }   

    // In the right or left cases, we need to switch scaledWidth and scaledHeight,
    // and also the thumbnail point
    if (sourceImage.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationLeft) {
        thumbnailPoint = CGPointMake(thumbnailPoint.y, thumbnailPoint.x);
        CGFloat oldScaledWidth = scaledWidth;
        scaledWidth = scaledHeight;
        scaledHeight = oldScaledWidth;

        CGContextRotateCTM (bitmap, M_PI_2); // + 90 degrees
        CGContextTranslateCTM (bitmap, 0, -targetHeight);

    } else if (sourceImage.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationRight) {
        thumbnailPoint = CGPointMake(thumbnailPoint.y, thumbnailPoint.x);
        CGFloat oldScaledWidth = scaledWidth;
        scaledWidth = scaledHeight;
        scaledHeight = oldScaledWidth;

        CGContextRotateCTM (bitmap, -M_PI_2); // - 90 degrees
        CGContextTranslateCTM (bitmap, -targetWidth, 0);

    } else if (sourceImage.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationUp) {
        // NOTHING
    } else if (sourceImage.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationDown) {
        CGContextTranslateCTM (bitmap, targetWidth, targetHeight);
        CGContextRotateCTM (bitmap, -M_PI); // - 180 degrees
    }

    CGContextDrawImage(bitmap, CGRectMake(thumbnailPoint.x, thumbnailPoint.y, scaledWidth, scaledHeight), imageRef);
    CGImageRef ref = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(bitmap);
    UIImage* newImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:ref];

    CGContextRelease(bitmap);
    CGImageRelease(ref);

    return newImage; 
}
```

And if you want to use them, you'd do something like:

```
UIImage* myThumbnail = ...; // Get some image
NSData* imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(myThumbnail);
```

to save it to disk,(say into the documents directory):

```
// Give a name to the file
NSString* imageName = @"MyImage.png";

// Now, we have to find the documents directory so we can save it
// Note that you might want to save it elsewhere, like the cache directory,
// or something similar.
NSArray* paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString* documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

// Now we get the full path to the file
NSString* fullPathToFile = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:imageName];

// and then we write it out
[imageData writeToFile:fullPathToFile atomically:NO];
```

Comment: When i am returning the image and saving it . its not saving. and log shows width 0 height 0. for that newImage

Answer (score 1):

```
if(image)
    {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(newWidth, newHeight));
        [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newWidth, newHeight)];
         imageAfterResize = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        ;
    }
```

Is this enough for you?

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
    self.testImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"youImage.png"]];
    self.testImageView.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 320, 480);
    [self.view addSubview:self.testImageView];
}

-(void)resizeImageToSize:(CGSize)targetSize
{
    self.testImageView.fram = targetSize;
}
```

Comment: i want to resize image not imageview. so image dont have frame property.